# How to persist only time using eclipseLink?

Tags: persistence, eclipselink

I have a timestamp attribute in my oracle 11g database table. I generated JPA entities from table and the timestamp attribute was created as a date entity. I only want to store and retrieve time values into the database. how to do this? I am using eclipseLink2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)` annotation

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date value;
```

Then only the time portion should be stored to the database.

If you're using the JPA Criteria API to create Queries, you should make sure that the Date portion is zero on existing data. I.e. on an Oracle Database if you query the data like `select to_char(timecolumn,'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from sometable` the result should look like `"01.01.1970 XX:XX:XX"`. Normally if you're using the JPA to store Time Values with `TemporalType.TIME` it will take care of that for you. If the Date portion isn't zero you may have problems comparing the time field.